# Mitigate SQL injection and keep current flexibility

Tags: c#, sql, data-access-layer

I need to update a C# .NET Framework library which handles most of our SQL tasks. Currently this library is vulnerable for SQL injection.

I found out that using parametrized queries safeguards against SQL injection.
However, for a lot of our programs we are using variable tableNames, variable columnNames and sometimes even a dynamic range of columns (i.e. after deployment, extra columns can be added to a table and the software can perform CRUD-actions on those).

From what I understand, when using parametrized queries, it is not possible to use a parameter for a columnName or tableName, unless you use EXEC(N''), but if I understand correctly this would make us vulnerable again to SQL injection?

Lastly, because of the need to support adding columns in a table post-deployment, I don't think it is possible to use a DAL like Entity Framework (without having to recompile the code after adding a column post-deployment).

I am a bit at a loss how I can resolve the vulnerability regarding SQL injection whilst still providing all the current 'dynamic' functionality.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: the solution for variable table names: _whitelisting_. the solution for variable columnNames: _fix your database_. that's just broken software design. that shouldn't have happened. i'm curious what problem you tried to solve by this, could you provide more info? then we _may_ be able to recommend better alternatives.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Cmon now, that's pretty harsh. What if it's a multi tenant where each customer can add their own custom columns to the table? e.g. like SAP/Dynamics/Salesforce...

Comment: Without an example of your code it's hard to assess whether there is a genuine issue with the approach preventing you from using statically compiled lists or there is just laziness from the developers. As @AKX pointed out in their answer, you want to whitelist the inputs. So the client(frontend etc) would NEVER be allowed to send raw query to the backend; it would ask for table names e.g. as a parameter in the request and you would validate those against schema (using the executing db principal to make sure visibility and access rules are enforced)

Comment: @zaitsman those examples you provided are the examples i would have provided for _terrible_ design ;) multi-tenant can be better solved with a query filter - or simply _multiple databases_, "custom value columns" can be better solved by a key-value-table, and if it's that big of a feature, a RDBMS is not the right choice in the first place IMHO.

Comment: Well, please tell that to Salesforce running on Oracle RDBMS with multi billion dollar business :))) Purity of software design does not equal commercial success and vice versa

Comment: To shed some light, the affected programs are backend-only (integration) components which can read data from one datasource, perform mutations on it and insert it into another datasource. Because we do not know upfront how the data of customers looks (and because this often changes after sometime), we write down each tableName, a list of their columnName and per columnName its action in a configuration file.
This would enable a potential attacker to update the configuration file and add additional SQL information, for example 'drop table X'. I am unsure how to mitigate and keep existing func.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann The way I read OP's question, they already have multiple databases (deployments), maybe for each tenant, and they all have slightly different schemata.

Comment: @zaitsman just because they've got a thriving business _in selling support for their software_ doesn't mean their _software_ is any good. and SO is about good code, not good profits

Comment: @DaGrooveNL so what you need is a database table describing Metadata (e.g. tables/column names). You would only grant READ to this table to the principal running your application. only humans with relevant access would be given WRITE to this table. Then you can write fully dynamic queries using metadata from that table knowing that even if an attacker injects something to modify this table the principal doesn't have permissions to do so.

Comment: @zaitsman How about if I merge your comment's solution (metadata table) with AKX's suggested solution of validating the table and column names? I.e. a-zA-Z0-9 and _ (underscore) only?

Comment: @DaGrooveNL That makes sense, you do want to sanitise client input regardless.

Answer (score 3):

In general, by stringently validating the user-entered data that can't be parametrized otherwise.

- To be as stringent as possible, use an allowlist of allowed terms. Since you say you need to be able to add columns post-deployment, you could interrogate the particular database's schema to build that list of allowed words.
- To be more flexible without the need to figure out an allowlist, come up with other validation, e.g. a regular expression that matches the terms that you should allow, but doesn't allow for SQL injection. For instance, if all of those column names or table names are always lower-case with underscores, if all the user-entered terms match the regular expression `^[a-z_]+$`, there's little chance for any shenanigans.

Comment: I was indeed also thinking about perhaps limiting the name of columns to a-zA-Z0-9 and an underscore. Any parameter coming in could then be verified against this and if no match, an error could be raised and the job aborted. I would assume this would largely negate potential SQL injection attacks, but I am not 100% confident about this.

Comment: You would need to make sure the input is not e.g. exactly a number though, to avoid `WHERE 1 = 1` style attacks.

Comment: Yes, that is a good one. Do you think if I would actively check against length > 1, with atleast 1 alphabetic character and limiting non alphanumeric characters to underscore _ only (so no =, whitespace or anything else), this could be a safe way to mitigate sql injection for dynamic table and column names? Each tableName and columnName is also wrapped inside [ ].

Comment: That sounds safe to me, especially if you pinky-swear to wrap those names in brackets like that. :)

Comment: Maybe `^[a-z][a-z0-9_]*$` would be enough – must have at least one leading alphabet, can have alphanumerics and underscores thereafter.